# How to exclude the records Using Qualify statement in Teradata

Tags: teradata, qualifiers

I have to create population for the people who has only one product association (ABC) using qualify statement.

For example I have the data

```
Id  Code  Prod  Date
101  202   ABC   2017-05-31
101  203   DEF   2017-04-30
102  302   ABC   2018-06-30
```

From the above data I need the data for Id=102 because this id has only one prod relation where as id 101 has both ABC and DEF which should be excluded.

I tried the following

```
 Select id,prod from table1
 Qualify row_number() over (partition by id order by Date)=1
Where prod=‘ABC’
```

With this, I get the two records in my data which I don’t want. Appreciate your help.

Comment: This query gives you two rows because the `WHERE` is applied first and then the `ROW_NUMBER()` gives you one row per each unique `Id` (in this case 101 and 102).  See below for another option.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select *
from table1
Qualify min(Prod) over (partition by id)='ABC'
    and max(Prod) over (partition by id)='ABC'
```

Both MIN and MAX return the same value ABC, thus there's no other value

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the id's that have one `prod` value (`ABC`) in the table, you can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT id, prod
FROM (
  SELECT id, prod
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY id, prod -- Get unique (id, prod) combinations
  QUALIFY COUNT(prod) OVER(PARTITION BY id) = 1 -- Get id's with only one prod
) src
WHERE prod = 'ABC' -- Only get rows with "ABC" prod
```

The key here is the order in which `Teradata` processes the query:

1. Aggregate - `GROUP BY`
2. OLAP - `COUNT(prod) OVER()`
3. QUALIFY

You may be able to move the `WHERE prod = 'ABC'` into the `QUALIFY` clause and get rid of the outer `SELECT`, not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

Just use having, instead of qualify. I don't see any need for window fuctions. Something like:

```
Select id,prod ,
count(prod)
from
table1
group by 
id,
prod
having count(prod) = 1
```

Comment: The way I read the question, the user only wants `id's` that have a single `prod` value, which must be `ABC`, so you'd need to account for that somewhere. I think Dieter's answer does the trick nicely.